# Why the time derivative lives in ${H^1}^*$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Assume we have a parabolic PDE. For sake of simplicity consider the heat equation defined on a "nice" domain:
$$\partial_t u(x,t)-\Delta u(x,t)=0$$
We know that the weak form of this PDE is:
$$\left< \dot{u}(t),v \right>_{H^1}+\left( \nabla u(t),\nabla v \right)_{\mathcal{L}^2}=0\qquad \forall \;v\in H^1 \qquad \forall\; t\;\;\mathrm{a.e.}$$
Where $\left< \cdot, \cdot\cdot \right>_{H^1}$ is representing the duality product in $H^1$.

In general, is it true that the derivative $u(t)$ of a function $u\in\mathcal{L}\left( 0,T;H^1 \right)$ is in the dual space ${H^1}^*$?

Comment: This is pretty natural once you've accepted the weak formulation of the equation. Since $v$ is in $H^1$, one requires that the duality pairing with $u'(t)$ makes sense, i.e. $u' \in H^{1*}$

Comment: You are right. But this is somehow a consequence. In order to have a weak solution $u$, $\dot{u}(t)$ must be in ${H^1}^*$. In general why the time derivative of a $H^1$ should leave in the dual? Is it true?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You made me realise the right formulation of my question.